# ZMQ pub sub subscription call

Tags: zeromq

This is a fairly simple question. Can I call 'zmq_setsockopt" multiple times to subscribe to multiple topics? An example below.

```
                    std::for_each(std::begin(subscriptions_), std::end(subscriptions_),
                    [&](SubscriptionMap::value_type & v)
                    {
                        subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, v.first.c_str(), v.first.size());
                    });
```

Ramesh

Comment: You can. Also.. you could have tried before asking :)

Comment: Indeed could have tried ... (-: Thank you for the response.